# How to create single get method with parameter to return specific field

Tags: java, metaprogramming

Is there any way in Java to create a meta **get** method that can return any field of the class by using an argument to specify field's name? In other word is there any method in java that can parse values of string variables into variable names. for example some thing like this:

```
class A{
    private int x;
    private int y;
    public get(String fieldName){
        return evaluate(fieldName); // I am looking for an equivalent to evaluate function that can represent field name (x or y)
    }
}
```

Please notice that the evaluate function is not working as it is my question.

Comment: Why not use a `java.util.Map<String, Object>` for it? You can even extend HashMap or something to enrich the functionality...

Comment: Yes there is a method, but it's considered poor practice. Just do it with a switch statement and Enums.

Comment: You can use reflections to do this.